# Rounding all corners with cornerRadius works, but if I just do the bottom two it breaks scrolling on my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, calayer

**Example project:** http://cl.ly/1l1x1A0J3o2X

I have a child view controller that has a UITableView in it, and this view controller sits on top of another view controller. I want to give the bottom of it rounded corners (but only the bottom).

In my UITableView subclass I have this code to round the bottom corners.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.169 green:0.169 blue:0.169 alpha:1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Which does indeed round them, but as soon as I scroll the table view it moves it up further and decreases in height (seemingly at least).

However, if I simply use `self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0` it completely operates fine.

Does anyone know why this behaviour might be the case?

Comment: What do you mean "moves it up further?" What is "it"? The cell? The mask? Are you using auto-layout? IF so a constraint might be resizing your cell's layer. I don't remember if the system resizes a layer's mask layer automatically or not.

Comment: Sorry. Visibly it looks like the tableview is shifted upwards as I scroll, instead of its scrollview. Here's an example project where I mask the containing view of the table view in its view controller per the request of the answer: http://cl.ly/1l1x1A0J3o2X but if you simply move that to the table view's `initWithCoder` it creates the effect we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView, and thus the subclass UITableView, actually renders its content by changing the bounds of what it's rendering. My guess is that adding a mask to the UITableView's layer is actually adding the mask to the content within the view, not the container like you might imagine.

Why 'self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0' works, and your approach doesn't, I am not sure.

An approach that would work better was already given for a similar request, so I'll direct you over to:

[Adding Rounded Corners to only top of UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621798/adding-rounded-corners-to-only-top-of-uitableview)

Basically, the recommendation was to put the UITableView into a container and add the mask to the container. I believe that would work just fine.

Comment: Here's an example project: http://cl.ly/1l1x1A0J3o2X I tried in the `viewDidLoad` of that view controller adding the mask to `self.view.layer` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You could also set the mask to have the size of the table view's *frame*, then, in `scrollViewDidScroll:`, adjust the position of the mask so that it stays pinned to the visible portion of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact answer. But I am gonna give you an workaround.

Look at this question and answer.

[How to get an UITableView working with CAShapeLayer mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11342236/1083859)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11538923/1083859

This will give you a clue what I tried.

As in that question explained, adding `tableView` mask will not going to work for you, because it will move with your `tableView` as you explained.
So I tried adding a another `superview` for the `tableView` in your `DropDownViewController` and add a outlet for it.

[image]

Then I changed your code inside the `viewDidLoad` in `DropDownViewController` to add the `mask` for current `superview` of `tableView` like below.

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.tableSuperView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.tableSuperView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

and that's it. It works. And I found an unwanted behavior when scroll the `tableView` to the end. It happens because of `tableView` bounce animation. If you remove that animation, then you are good to go.

Glad to know your opinion and result.